# Materialized View how to set a refresh time with task?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to set a task to refresh a materialized view every hour. I have tried this:

1. I ran and INSERT of new data to the original table. The Materialized View updated instantly
2. Forcing the table to drop, the undrop the table that makes up the materialized view. It resulted in a full restoration at the specific time - though this would get expensive quickly

`Drop table BookInventory;`

`Undrop table BookInventory;`

I could not find anything in documentation on scheduling a creation of a materilaized view. Has anyone done this before?

Comment: But why? Snowflake automatically keeps your materialized views up to date when a DML is ran against its base table. Furthmore if your base table is experiencing this much change each hour, then a materialized view may not be the right solution. Generally a materialized view is recommended when its base table doesn't experience much change and the materialized view sql is ran often and is expensive (IO and Compute wise).

Comment: However, if you are committed to causing a refresh of your materialized view every hour, then you can use [`TRUNCATE MATERIALIZED VIEW <viewname>`](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/truncate-materialized-view.html) to trigger a refresh. While it's refreshing, queries made against the view will be performed against the base table and will be slower as a result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can suspend and resume materialized views. But you cannot query a suspended MV.  What are you trying to accomplish?  You are not going to save money, only defer the cost.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is that you simply create your own "materialized view" via a custom procedure that you can schedule via a task.

the procedure creates a temp table like the current, including grants.  Then inserts the data into this table from a view.  Finally swap the tables and drop the temp table.  Best to create this as a Transient table since there's no need for Time Travel.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE utl.arch_create_mview_sp(P_TABLE_NM VARCHAR, P_VIEW_NM VARCHAR)
  RETURNS STRING
  LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
  EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS $$
  var result = "";
  var sqlCmd = "";
  var rs = "";
  var tmpTableNM = P_TABLE_NM + "_tmp";

  try {
    sqlCmd = "CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE " + tmpTableNM + " LIKE " + P_TABLE_NM + " COPY GRANTS";
    snowflake.execute( {sqlText: sqlCmd} );

    sqlCmd = "INSERT INTO " + tmpTableNM + " SELECT * FROM " + P_VIEW_NM;
    rs = snowflake.execute( {sqlText: sqlCmd} );
    rs.next();

    result = "rows inserted: " + rs.getColumnValue(1);

    sqlCmd = "ALTER TABLE " + P_TABLE_NM + " SWAP WITH " + tmpTableNM;
    snowflake.execute( {sqlText: sqlCmd} );

    sqlCmd = "DROP TABLE " + tmpTableNM;
    snowflake.execute( {sqlText: sqlCmd} );
  }
  catch (err) {
      result =  "Failed: Code: " + err.code + " | State: " + err.state;
      result += "\n  Message: " + err.message;
      result += "\nStack Trace:\n" + err.stackTraceTxt; 
    }
  }
  return result;
$$;
```